# Alternative description of the sheafification

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

For me the sheafification of a given presheaf is this:

> **Proposition-Definition:** Given a presheaf $\mathscr{F}$, there is a sheaf $\mathscr{F}^+$ and a morphism $\theta \colon \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{F}^+$, with the property that for any sheaf $\mathscr{G}$, and any morphism $\varphi \colon \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{G}$, there is a unique morphism $\psi \colon \mathscr{F}^+ \to \mathscr{G}$ such that $\varphi = \psi \circ \theta$. Furthermore the pair $(\mathscr{F}^+, \theta)$ is unique up to unique isomorphism. $\mathscr{F}^+$ is called the *sheaf associated* to the presheaf $\mathscr{F}$.

I know that this is equivalent to a universally repelling object in a certain category. But how could this be equal to the following?

> Suppose $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathscr{S}$, where $\mathscr{S}$ is a sheaf. Then we define 
>   $$
>  \mathcal{F}^+ =
>  \left\{
>   s \in \mathscr{S}(U)
>   \,\middle|\,
>   \forall U \in \tau (X) :
>   \text{$s$ is locally in $\mathcal{F}(U)$}
>  \right\}
> $$
>   for a fixed topological space $X$. By *locally in $\mathcal{F}(U)$* we mean that given $s \in \mathscr{S}(U)$ there exists an open covering $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $U$ such that $s|_{U_\alpha} \in \mathcal{F}(U_{\alpha}) \subset \mathscr{S}(U_{\alpha})$.

The thing is that the only tool I have so far is the definition, so how can I get this? I know that I have to verify the universal property of my new $\mathcal{F}^{+}$ but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: Why do you start supposing that the presheaf $\mathcal F$ is contained in a sheaf $\mathcal S$?

Comment: Is the definition I have :(

Comment: Ah, alright, I thought you had made it up yourself. :) Where does it come from?

Comment: Well I don't know :( jajaja the profesor only gave us but I had as definition the first one so I want to make sure that both conside :)

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: What's stopping you? Suppose you have $\varphi\colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ into a sheaf. For $s \in \mathcal{F}^+(U)$ you have a cover $\{V_i\}$ of $U$ such that $s|_{V_i} \in \mathcal{F}(V_i)$. Check that the $\varphi(s|_{V_i})$ glue together to give an element $t \in \mathcal{G}(U)$ and define $\psi(s) = t$. There's a lot of annoying stuff to check but I don't think any of it requires me to be too clever.

Comment: But I have to check the universal property described in the post right? And I think that in your above comment you only want to prove that my $\mathcal{F}^{+}$ is a sheaf and proving the universal property guarantees that $\mathcal{F}^{+}$ is a sheaf right?

Comment: You have to check the universal property, yes; I am telling you how to start doing that. Of course you should verify first that $\mathcal{F}^+$ is a sheaf (that's part of the universal property) but I'm assuming that's not so hard either.

Comment: Ok, let me do that but if I need further help can I let you know, it could take some time :)

Comment: How do you get the first property of sheaves with your above idea?

Comment: I think is trivial since $f,g \in \mathcal{F}^{+}$ implies $f,g \in \mathcal{S}$ that is sheaf by assumption right?

Comment: I assume by first property you mean the "identity axiom" or whatever you want to call it. I think $\mathcal{F}^+$ inherits that from $\mathcal{S}$. And of course elements of $\mathcal{F}^+$ "glue" inside of $\mathcal{S}$, so the only thing to check is that the result actually belongs to $\mathcal{F}^+$.

Comment: Yes but how do you do that last part is your comment ? Sorry for the delay

Comment: Is because I was trying to argue as follows: $\phi |_{V_i}$ glue as $\phi |_{U}$ right ?

Comment: @Hoot Once I assume $f,g \in \mathcal{F}^{+}$ we know that $f=g$ is they agree in covering of a open set, but now, how do you make sure that $f,g$ are locally in $\mathcal{F}$? I think this is true because since the beginning we are taking $f,g \in \mathcal{F}^{+}$

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Answer (score 2):

Your highlighted definition intuitively says that the sheafification $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F^{+}}$ only does what every map from  $\mathcal{F}$ to a sheaf must do.  Literally: sheafification adds just enough new sections to  $\mathcal{F}$ to make  a sheaf, and merges together just enough sections of  $\mathcal{F}$ -- so every map from  $\mathcal{F}$ to a sheaf factors through the sheafification.

The second definition uses a presumed embedding  $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathscr{S}$ into a sheaf to say explicitly what sections must be added.  If  $\mathcal{F}$ has an embedding into a sheaf, then no sections need to be merged.

But of course the sheafification might not be all of $\mathscr{S}$.  It will use just those sections in the set

$$\{s \in \mathscr{S}(U) \; \big{|} \; s \;\text{is locally in} \; \mathcal{F}(U)\; \forall U \in \tau (X) \}$$

Comment: Ok, I know the first part but how does that prove directly that I have the universal property?

Comment: @user162343  I do not understand your comment question.  The first part *says* sheafication has the universal property.  What more do you want to know?

Comment: Oh is because I was expecting something like: we define $\theta: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F^{+}}$ as... then for a given sheaf $\mathcal{S}$ we have the factorization of $\phi : \mathcal{F^{+}} \to \mathcal{S}$...  :)

Comment: Then what do you say? :)

Comment: In fact I read in the other question on MO that $\theta$ will be the inclusion with restricted domain, so what can be done?

Comment: Let me check your edition, just a second

Comment: So how can you prove this explicitly not just intuitively?

Comment: Then what can be done?

Comment: @user162343 What more do you want done?  What remains unclear to you?

Comment: Is because as I told you in my previous comments, How can you explain your answer not intuitively but with the explicit calculations ? :)

Comment: After an initial intuitive gloss, my answer describes the calculations, as does @Hoot in comments.

Comment: Ok so your answer count as a detailed proof right ? , and another thing if I get something about the calculations can I posted for your verifications?

Comment: Once I assume $f,g \in \mathcal{F}^{+}$ we know that $f=g$ is they agree in covering of a open set, but now, how do you make sure that $f,g$ are locally in $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: I have edited my post :)